# Microservices response model class

Tags: java, architecture, microservices

I am developing microservice application and i got stuck on duplicated models.
I have lets say 4 services A B C D. Each service has its own database and i need to call service D from other services ( A B C ). Which means that i have to create duplicated Response class in each service.

Lets say that i would have 100 services and service D will change model it will be bad for change. I found as another option to create library and dependency. I am  working in Java but creating .jar library as dependency would not allow me to implement other services in other language so i consider this as bad approach as well.

I am of course trying to avoid coupling services so can t add dependency to all service.

My question is that is there any other better way to provide response model to other services ? If possibly somehow generated from json or just simple 1 place from where it would be builded to other microservices ?
Thank you for responses

Comment: Yes. Auto-generate the response model. That is what swagger and OpenAPI plus the corresponding code-generators are for.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, you standardise your response by implementing the standard API response. For example, each response should have a standard transaction ID. Ideally, you can have this base response in common or shared library used by all the microservices.

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    @JsonProperty
    private String transactionId;

    ...
}
```

Each `microservice` API response will extend the base response (i.e. `ApiResponse`) response

```
public class MyServiceApiResponse extends ApiResponse
{
    @JsonProperty
    public String country;

    @JsonProperty
    public List<City> cities;

    public MyServiceApiResponse(String transactionId, String country, List<City> cities)
    {
        super(transactionId);
        this.country = country;
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    ....
}
```

The API controller returns response like this. For example:

```
@GetMapping(path = PATH)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public MyServiceApiResponse getCountry(String transactionId, String country)
{
    ...

   List<City> cities = getCities(country);
   ....

   return new MyServiceApiResponse(transactionId, country, cities);
}
```